# Can ReadyBoost cause startup problems?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

I use an HP flash drive as a ReadyBoost drive for my laptop (which is also HP)
Of late, I have observed that the computer hangs during the startup process, at the logo screen.

There are no hard drive reads as the hard drive light goes off and does not come back on.
So I tried the `Startup Repair` test and it determined that there was no root cause of the problem. For now I have disconnected the flash drive.

My uneducated conclusion is that the OS thinks that it has loaded the necessary files in the flash drive and stops reading from the HDD which causes the startup to hang. The flash drive is not empty, though. It has some other files in it, too.

I checked the drive for errors using `CrystalDiskInfo` and `HD Tune v5.0` and found no problems.

### What could be the cause of the problem?

Also, would it be recommended to keep the flash drive plugged into the USB for `ReadyBoost` or to attach it after the laptop starts?

**Misc:**
OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit
Laptop: HP Pavilion DV4-2126tx
HDD: WD Scorpio Black 500GB, AF Drive
Frequency of this problem: Twice in the past two days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the hot fix and see if that helps. 
[Fix373779](http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/Windows%207/Windows%20Server2008%20R2%20SP1/sp2/Fix373779/7600/free/435137_intl_i386_zip.exe)

If it doesn't, go to run and type msconfig, startup tab, and disable everything. Restart and see if that helped.

Lastly, I would say it was a driver issue. Remember, drivers load before the GUI, so I would go in services.msc, click on the status tab twice to sort all running services, and set anything odd looking to manual.

Deactivating Windows defender and or DEP also quickens things up.

My last bit of advice, which is actually my first bit if you happen to have it on your PC, is to remove McAffe anti-virus from your computer. McAffe drops performance by huge margins.

Let me know.

Comment: I have installed the hot fix. I will let you know in a couple of days if the problem is solved. If it persists, I will let you know in this thread :) Till then, I am accepting this as the correct answer.

Comment: It can be if it persists. My memory is a bit foggy on this, but I believe race conditions are two threads attempting to change a variables state at the same time. The details are not really important, it's basically a multiple access violation and normally happens once in a great while. Let me know if it becomes a constant thing.

Comment: You are a Java enthusiast, too ? I learn Java mostly on my own so I guess it would be more productive if we club resources / experience (although I do not know how)

Comment: I am a C#.NET developer, but at there core there is almost no difference between them. Same syntax and structure. Definitely keep at it.